# jupyter declarativewidgets change style

Tags: css, widget, ipython, jupyter, declarative

In my jupyter notebook, I want to have an interactive table, that when the user selects a row, I show relevant values in another table or graph.

What I am currently trying to use is declarativewidgets (although if an easier alternative was presented, I would be just as glad)

I had no problem setting up an example worked fine, and it was trivial to link the event from one item to the next, but I have been unable to change the styling of the elements. In particular, I want to be able to control the background color (and even make it alternate by row) on a table by table basis. I mean, I will have several tables (the first linked to the next, linked to the next, etc.), and I want each table to have a different background color.

What I have so far:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from ipywidgets import *
import declarativewidgets
import pandas as pd
declarativewidgets.init()
```

Then I import the urth-viz-table:

```
%%html
<link rel="import" href="urth_components/urth-viz-table/urth-viz-table.html" 
    is='urth-core-import'>
```

Then I have a function

```
def create_df():
    return pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
           'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])})
```

And the next cell creates the first table:

```
%%html
<template is="urth-core-bind">
    <urth-core-function ref="create_df"
                    result="{{create_df}}" 
                    limit="1600"
                    delay="100" 
                    auto>
    </urth-core-function>
    <urth-viz-table datarows="{{ create_df.data }}" 
                rows-visible="19" 
                selection="{{first_selection}}" 
                columns="{{ create_df.columns }}" 
                selection-as-object>
    </urth-viz-table>
</template>
```

This works fine, and I am able to create new tables and graphs and link them to the behaviour of the previous table. What I have not been able to do is change any of the styling of the table, an specific example would be greatly appreciated.

I am using 
python                     3.6
jupyter                    4.2.1
jupyter-dashboards         0.6.1
jupyter-declarativewidgets 0.7.0